# How to update Reboot CSS in Blazor Server

Tags: css, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am using Blazor Server to write an app. I am trying to update the CSS and it does not seem to be taking.

**More detail:**
I have used [MSFT Convert Standard Nav Menu](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/web-development/convert-the-standard-blazor-navigation-menu-to-a-collapsible/m-p/3753268) to make a nice-looking side menu that supports sub-menu components. I am looking to change the padding on the elements. Using the Chrome Developer console, I have isolated the CSS and changed it to my liking. However, when I find that very same CSS in my project, it doesn't work! To be clear I found the CSS in wwwroot/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css/bootstrap.css.min.map.

[image: Chrome Developer Screenshot]

**What have I tried:**

1. Clearing the cache
2. Using different browsers and incognito mode
3. Searching the CSS exhaustively to ensure there is nothing else I am missing.

I am not a web developer by trade, so all help is appreciated.

Comment: If I understand correctly you modified the original CSS boostrap file. If yes, you souldn't do that, this is an external library, you might want to update it. You should create a custom CSS file and override the styling from there. Don't forget to call this CSS file after bootstrap file.

Comment: For some reason, I couldn't get it to work exactly the same, but I was able to override the property and get it almost perfect. Thank you for the tip and advice.  If you set it as the answer I'll mark it as such :)

Comment: @Rob, Please reread my question. I would have posted the code if I asked someone why it was not working. I was asking a functional question for a functional response. I specifically needed to highlight it the way it looked in a developer console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not edit directly files from imported libraries because upgrading those to newer versions may overwrite your code: remembering what you modified/added would be a pain.

Moreover, bootstrap files are often minified, which makes it even less clear but suggests that it shouldn't be edited.

Simply create a custom css file to override bootstrap styling. Make sure to call the file after bootstrap.